# Django admin: order by custom python function

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, django-admin

I have `IntEnum` called `FieldType`. I'm saving type's int value in the database. How to order not by type's int, but by its name?

If I'm right, because I only save ints in database and transform them to strings in Python, I cannot rely on django's `admin.ModelAdmin.ordering` or `queryset.order_by`?

Here is my `ModelAdmin`, that by idea, should get type name by inserting its int value from db (function `type_name`) and order by type's name.

```
class OrderFieldRegexByType(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('type_name', 'pattern')

    def type_name(self, obj):
        return FieldType(obj.type).name

    type_name.admin_order_field = 'type_name__pattern'
```